# View lifecycle in iOS 8.3

Tags: segue, lifecycle, ios8.3

In my app, many view controllers have a Container View containing a sort of "dashboard", with several buttons and labels shared throughout the app.
When segueing between two view controllers, what normally happens is:

```
1) the new view controller's viewDidLoad is called;
2) the new view controller's viewWillAppear is called;
3) the dashboard's viewDidLoad is called (there is an automatic segue to it, since it's inside a Container View);
4) the dashboard's viewWillAppear is called;
```

Now, in the dashboard's viewWillAppear method, I do some formatting of the different labels (changing their text and color). However, in iOS 8.3 this seems to have no effect. For example, I do the following to change a button's label:

```
self.myButton.titleLabel.text = @"myText";
```

and yet, right after the execution of this instruction, doing a

```
(lldb) po self.myButton.titleLabel.text
```

at the debugger prompt, will output the previous content of that button's label (from the storyboard) instead of "myText". Needless to say, everything works fine up to iOS 8.2 (including iOS 7).

So my question is: was anything changed at the view/segue lifecycle level in iOS 8.3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `[myButton setTitle:forState:]` to change the title of a button. If it worked before, it was by pure luck.